# How do i restart apache in windows sysstem

Tags: apache, restart

I want to restart my apache2 in my windows system,for that i have tried the following command "httpd -k -restart"
but I am getting an error "The system cannot find the file specified.  : AH00436: No installed service named "Apache2.4".
I checked my apache version and it is 2.

Comment: HELPFULL : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116757/apache-xampp-command-line-start-error-ah00436-no-installed-service-named-apac

Answer (score 0):

I think the service is not registered in windows registry try

```
httpd -k install
```

Answer (score 0):

As the official [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html#page-header) says after you installed apache as **"MyServiceName"** you can use this command:

```
httpd.exe -k restart -n "MyServiceName"
```

Answer (score 0):

The restart action causes Apache to reload and apply its configuration, without actually restarting the process or breaking any opened client connection, causing a so called "graceful reload".
You can check it by yourself with Windows Task Manager, the Apache PID (Process ID) won't change after a restart.

However, any action triggered by the option `-k` (they are called [signals](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/stopping.html)), needs the Apache service to exist in Windows services list.
Therefore, if you see this error message, there are only two possible causes:

### Your Apache service does not exist

Then just create it with

```
httpd.exe -h install
```

Now you should be able to send the restart signal

```
httpd.exe -k restart
```

### Your Apache service has a custom name

If the service exists, but has a custom name such as "My Awesome Apache Service", then you have to specify that name when you want to send it any signal.

So, if you have installed it with

```
httpd.exe -k install -n "My Awesome Apache Service"
```

you have to restart it with

```
httpd.exe -k restart -n "My Awesome Apache Service"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolute path to your `httpd.exe` file. Something like this in cmd should work:

```
C:\64bit\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe -k restart
```